# How is it possible to be saved through "grace alone" if you have to be baptized to be saved?

Tags: baptism

If salvation is by grace alone, no works necessary, then why did Jesus say to Nicodemus "Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born of water and of the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God." (John 3:5).  That sounds like baptism to me, and baptism sounds like "doing something" (aka "works").

Comment: easy answer is baptism is an expression of salvation not a means, otherwise the thief on the cross would not have been saved

Comment: And I will add, all churches that subscribe to the Nicene creed give lip service to Acts 2:38 saying "we acknowledge one baptism for the remission of sins." Why do they do that, unless they know baptism is indeed required, despite their constant insistence that it isn't?

Comment: How does baptism oppose grace?  Whatever work is done inside baptism is done by God, while you just stand there and get dunked.